# PHP regex to match alphanumeric and hyphens (not spaces) for use as subdomain

Tags: php, regex, subdomain

I have the following regex, which I interpret as a pattern that will match a string consisting of just alphanumeric characters and hyphens.

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9-]/', $subdomain) === false) {
    // valid subdomain
}
```

The problem is this regex is also matching blank spaces, which is obviously undesirable in a subdomain name.

For bonus points, is this a suitable way to validate subdomain names? I'm unsure which special characters are allowed but thought I would keep it simple by only allowing hyphens. Is there anything else I need to check for? For instance a maximum length?

Comment: This matches a single character, add + to the end of [A-Za-z0-9-].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your pattern matches an ASCII letter or digit or `-` *anywhere* inside a string, and if found, returns true. E.g., it will return true if you pass `$#$%$&^$g` to it.

A pattern that will match a string consisting of just alphanumeric characters and hyphens is

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/D', $subdomain)) {
    // valid subdomain
}
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more chars that are either ASCII letters, digits or `-`
- `$` - end of string
- `/D` - a PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY modifier that makes the `$` anchor match at the very end of the string (excluding the position before the final newline in the string).

Comment: That still appears to match spaces?

Comment: Ignore that - preg_match returns 0 rather than false, and I was using the absolute equality operator and `false === 0 = false`

Comment: To expand this, how would I ensure the hyphen is not the last character in the string?

Comment: You need to use `'/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$(?<!-)/D'` or `'/^[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]$/D'`