# pattern to allow an optional hyphen between 2 alpha numerics and restrict space as well

Tags: javascript, regex

sub:  pattern to allow an optional hyphen between 2 alphanumeric and restrict space as well.No other specialcharacters

I need a regex to match following test cases:-

> "all-owed" "allowe-d" "a-llo-wed-12" "allowed12" "allow-12ed"
>   "allowed-12" "allo-wed-12"
>
> "not allowed" "not allowed " " notallowed" " nota-llowed"
>   "not--allowed" "not@allowed"

patterns tried:

```
^[^-]*-?[^-]*$
^\\w+(-\\w+)*$
```

[Regex to text a string which will have only numbers and an optional hyphen. Hyphen can be at any position after character 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577655/regex-to-text-a-string-which-will-have-only-numbers-and-an-optional-hyphen-hyph)

[javascript regex for special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters)

[Java regex - alphanumeric, at most one hyphen, period or underscore, seven characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103682/java-regex-alphanumeric-at-most-one-hyphen-period-or-underscore-seven-chara)

[PHP regex to match alphanumeric and hyphens (not spaces) for use as subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558881/php-regex-to-match-alphanumeric-and-hyphens-not-spaces-for-use-as-subdomain)

and some more

PLEASE POST THE DUPLICATE QUESTION LINK. We may learn from the solutions provided there and improve our search

Comment: The link to the dupe is displayed on top of your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second regex [`^\w+(-\w+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/khquOZ/1) would match your cases but `\w` would also match an underscore.

Perhaps you are looking for a pattern that matches one or more times an alphanumberic `[a-z0-9]+` and then repeats matching a dash followed by one or more times matching an alphanumeric `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*`

Note that this matches only lowercase characters. You can use the case insensitive flag to match both upper and lowercase characters.

[`^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xYQVTP/2)

```js
const strings = [
  "all-owed",
  "allowe-d",
  "a-llo-wed-12",
  "allowed12",
  "allow-12ed",
  "allowed-12",
  "allo-wed-12",
  "notallo-wed-12_",
  "not allowed",
  "not allowed ",
  " notallowed",
  " nota-llowed",
  "not--allowed",
  "not@allowed"
];
let pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: Tried ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$ it worked

Comment: @MayankParnami That could work [`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/fD7yQd/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookbehind and lookahead to ensure that `-` is between two alphanumeric characters.

`^((?<=\w)-(?=\w)|\w|\d)*$`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/kiX4sl/1)